# TypeError: DATA.total_cases is undefined ,cant find error?

Tags: javascript, html, api

hey im new to web dev and I am making a covid 19 tracker website and stuggling with this bug plz help
Issue with total_cases,total_recovered,total_deaths and last.entry.total_recovered

```
const country_name_element = document.querySelector(".country .name");
const total_cases_element = document.querySelector(".total-cases .value");
const new_cases_element = document.querySelector(".total-cases .new-value");
const recovered_element = document.querySelector(".recovered .value");
const new_recovered_element = document.querySelector(".recovered .new-value");
const deaths_element = document.querySelector(".deaths .value");
const new_deaths_element = document.querySelector(".deaths .new-value");
```

```
    })
    .then( data => {
        dates = Object.keys(data);
        
        dates.forEach( date => {
            let DATA = data[date];

            formatedDates.push(formatDate(date));
            app_data.push(DATA);
            cases_list.push(parseInt(DATA.total_cases.replace(/,/g, "")));
            recovered_list.push(parseInt(DATA.total_recovered.replace(/,/g, "")));
            deaths_list.push(parseInt(DATA.total_deaths.replace(/,/g, "")));
        })
    })
```

```
function updateStats(){
    let last_entry = app_data[app_data.length - 1];
    let before_last_entry = app_data[app_data.length - 2];

    country_name_element.innerHTML = last_entry.country_name;

    total_cases_element.innerHTML = last_entry.total_cases || 0;
    new_cases_element.innerHTML = `+${last_entry.new_cases || 0 }`;

    recovered_element.innerHTML = last_entry.total_recovered || 0;
    new_recovered_element.innerHTML = `+${parseInt(last_entry.total_recovered.replace(/,/g, "")) - parseInt(before_last_entry.total_recovered.replace(/,/g, ""))}`;
    
    deaths_element.innerHTML = last_entry.total_deaths;
    new_deaths_element.innerHTML = `+${last_entry.new_deaths || 0}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to debug this would be to open up your browsers Developer Tools and enable the option to "Pause on exceptions".

Chrome: View->Developer->Developer Tools-> Select "Sources" Tab-> The "Pause on exceptions" button.

Firefox has something similar: Tools->Web Developer->Debugger-> Breakpoints "Pause on exceptions".

Or just use the old fashioned: console.log(DATA)

Comment: I tried it, its showing the same error TypeError: DATA.total_cases is undefined what should I  do next

Comment: Well if you get "TypeError: DATA.total_cases" it means that "DATA" does not have a property called "total_cases" set. Do you see any other properties on "DATA" in the console? I can't see from your question where the data is coming from, or if it should always have that property.

Comment: I am using rapid api fetch("https://covid19-monitor-pro.p.rapidapi.com/coronavirus/cases_by_country_paginated.php?page=%3Crequired%3E&country=%3Crequired%3E&limit=%3Crequired%3E", {
 "method": "GET",
 "headers": {
  "x-rapidapi-host": "covid19-monitor-pro.p.rapidapi.com",
  "x-rapidapi-key": "2406d619fbmsh3e12d4fa0d35484p1c63c9jsn0404e4a39e3b"
 }

Comment: OK. So if you do a console.log(DATA) what do you see? You may just need to write your code to handle the property not being present. The API doc doesn't clearly state the response format.

Comment: console states DATA is not defined but it is defined in the second code snippet

Comment: So if you put a console.log(data) above the line "dates = Object.keys(data);" do you get an Object that has a range of dates as property keys? Can you post the response?

Comment: these 3 texts--- Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///C:/Users/Tanmya/Downloads/corona(1)/corona/jquery-3.4.1.min.js”. index.html:15:1
Use of mozImageSmoothingEnabled is deprecated. Please use the unprefixed imageSmoothingEnabled property instead. widget.js:1:10474
Object { message: "You are not subscribed to this API." }

Comment: Your call to the API is failing. That is why the response is "{ message: "You are not subscribed to this API." }", hence "DATA.total_cases" is undefined. I suggest you use their in-browser tool to get the exact JS that will make the correct API call. Note you will obviously need to be subscribed to RapidAPI to use it.